# Deleting rows in bulk google sheets using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a bulk sheet(more that 10000 rows) and 5 filters. I have to delete row if any of 5 columns is TRUE.

Comment: do you mean "TRUE" as a string or true as a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

#### Delete row with five "TRUE"

```
function lfunko2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Leads");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();//row 2 is start of data
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if(r.filter(c => c == "TRUE").length > 4) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  });
}
```